# how do i call the action name from the web.xml instead of typing the action name at the url of the browser

Tags: struts2

In My struts2 application i have a struts2 tag checkboxlist something like this

```
 <s:checkboxlist name="yourSelect" label="Are You Inteterested In"    
       list="communityList" value="defaultSelect" />
```

i added the list elements in my action class constuctor

view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

```
 public CustomerAction()  
      {  
         communityList = new ArrayList<String>();  
            communityList.add("WebSpere Consultuing");  
          communityList.add("Portal Consulting");  
          communityList.add("SOA/BPM Consulting");  
            communityList.add("Content Management");  
    }
```

public CustomerAction() { communityList = new ArrayList(); communityList.add("WebSpere Consultuing"); communityList.add("Portal Consulting"); communityList.add("SOA/BPM Consulting"); communityList.add("Content Management"); }

and i can very well display it on the jsp page ,

But the problem is when i call the jsp page in the web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>/pages/Customer.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

list is not populating , when i request the action name from the struts.xml of the Class whose constructor has the list values then the list is populating

how do i call the action name from the web.xml as a welcome-list-file instead of typing the action name at the url .....

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple JSP with an redirect.

```
<% response.sendRedirect("myaction.action"); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new welcome jsp or html file with this in its `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL = /project/MyAction.action"/>
```

This will invoke your Struts2 action, which will handle populating the ArrayList and forwarding you to your real welcome page.

[This thread](http://old.nabble.com/Action-as-Welcome-File-td19089710.html) has some other tips that may work as well.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer its working fine ,now i can call the action class in the url to load the checkboxlist values ,but if i call the action class to render the jsp page ,The is displaying along with the validation . Actually the validation should appear after i press the submit button in the page . not at the input time .So How can i solve this ?

Comment: You could create a method in your action class with a name like prep() that takes care of rendering the jsp, and then exclude prep() from your validation.  The excludeMethod parameter does this in the interceptor stack definition: http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/interceptors.html#Interceptors-MethodFiltering